# Is "all hands" TGIF meeting mandatory?

Tags: united-states, meetings, socializing, california

If the employer calls it an all-hands TGIF meeting, is it implying that the meeting is mandatory, or that everyone can attend, but doesn't have to?

Comment: The best thing is to ask your employer

Comment: Nothing is mandatory. You can skip an "all hands" meeting if you wish, but be prepared to answer why you did not attend if they ask you, and the potential fallout from it. By the way, what would you rather do instead of attending the meeting? Watch a movie perhaps?

Comment: @MaskedMan just about anything, including getting actual work done.

Comment: @MaxB What for?

Comment: @maxb if a company's senior management calls a 'all hands' meeting then this is very likely to be the 'actual work ' that senior management might like you to do. You can ignore that, of course, but eventually you're going to get marked as 'that guy' by management and that won't end well. Even if the meeting *is* a waste of your time, that's not entirely your call to make during working hours.

Comment: What does a TGIF meeting mean in this case? I am aware of what TGIF stands for, and normal interpretation would mean the meeting is a party, but this doesn't sound like that.

Comment: No, TGIF does not imply that it is mandatory. It may be, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, an "all hands" meeting implies that all employees are expected to attend.

Exceptions for this may include an employee being on previously-approved time off, illness, family emergency, or having required coverage of a service (customer service reps having to man phones, front desk receptionist, etc.).

But if you're at work and your being absent from your workstation will not cause a business-critical failure of some sort, you should probably attend at least briefly.